# Weird result when deleting or searching through database

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm learning how to use SQLite within Android studio and came across a weird issue when trying to delete things from the database. The table currently keeps track of three things, one is an int, and the other two are strings. When I try to delete, I pass the two strings only, since I don't really need the ID. If the strings contain any letters at all, the program fails, but if it consists of only numbers then it works perfectly. For example, if I try to delete something with the strings 456 and 654, then it will find and erase it, but if I try "Book" and "Pen", then it fails.

Also, when I'm searching through the database, if I search for everything at once, it works, but if I make the search more specific, it fails, and I'm not sure why. This is the code in my DataBaseHelper class:

```
public void RemoveOne(GameInformation gameInformation) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String queryString = "delete from " + GAME_TABLE +
                " where " + COLUMN_GAME_NAME + " like " + gameInformation.getName() +
                " and " + COLUMN_GAME_PLATFORM + " like " + gameInformation.getPlatform();
        db.execSQL(queryString);
        db.close();
    }

    public List<GameInformation> GetEverything() {
        String queryString = "select * from " + GAME_TABLE;
        return AddDbToArray(queryString);
    }


    public List<GameInformation> Search(GameInformation gameInformation) {
        String queryString = "select * from " + GAME_TABLE + " where " + COLUMN_GAME_NAME + " like " + gameInformation.getName();
        return AddDbToArray(queryString);
    }

    private List<GameInformation> AddDbToArray(String queryString) {
        List<GameInformation> returnList = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(queryString, null);
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                int gameID = cursor.getInt(0);
                String gameName = cursor.getString(1);
                String platform = cursor.getString(2);
                GameInformation gameInformation = new GameInformation(gameID, gameName, platform);
                returnList.add(gameInformation);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        } else {

        }
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return returnList;
    }
```

And this is the code in my MainActivity class:

```
    removeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String gameInput = gameTxt.getText().toString();
            String platformInput = platformTxt.getText().toString();

            GameInformation gameInformation = null;
            try {
                if (!gameInput.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !platformInput.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    gameInformation = new GameInformation(-1, gameInput, platformInput);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You missed some information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }
                dataBaseHelper.RemoveOne(gameInformation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something failed " + gameInformation.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            ShowGamesOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
        }
    });
    viewBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            ShowGamesOnListView(dataBaseHelper);
        }
    });

    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dataBaseHelper = new DataBaseHelper(MainActivity.this);
            GameInformation gameInformation = null;
            String platformName = platformTxt.getText().toString();
            String gameName = gameTxt.getText().toString();
            gameInformation = new GameInformation(-1, gameName, platformName);
            try {
                ShowSearchResultListView(dataBaseHelper, gameInformation);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Something went wrong with " + gameName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void ShowSearchResultListView(DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper, GameInformation gameInformation) {
    gameArrayAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<GameInformation>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataBaseHelper.Search(gameInformation));
    dbList.setAdapter(gameArrayAdaptor);
}

private void ShowGamesOnListView(DataBaseHelper dataBaseHelper) {
    gameArrayAdaptor = new ArrayAdapter<GameInformation>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, dataBaseHelper.GetEverything());
    dbList.setAdapter(gameArrayAdaptor);
}
```

Any advice on what I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume what is failing here is an unknown reference.

This is your query definition:

```
        String queryString = "delete from " + GAME_TABLE +
                " where " + COLUMN_GAME_NAME + " like " + gameInformation.getName() +
                " and " + COLUMN_GAME_PLATFORM + " like " + gameInformation.getPlatform();
```

When writing a SQL statement, the syntax looks like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/SQL/sql_like.asp):

```
SELECT column1, column2, ...
FROM table_name
WHERE columnN LIKE pattern;
```

For the `pattern` placeholder you need to write something like this:

```
WHERE CustomerName LIKE 'a%'    // Finds any values that start with "a"
```

Note that there are some '' single quotation marks.
So inside an SQL query you have to write a string in some kind of string notation.

Now in Android we can not write SQL code like on a command line. So actually we are writing a string in Java (or Kotlin) that exactly follows the SQL syntax.
In the end, it is still a string.

You are adding strings like this:

```
String queryString = "select * from " + GAME_TABLE + " where " + COLUMN_GAME_NAME + " like " + gameInformation.getName();
```

Where

```
String gameName = gameTxt.getText().toString();
```

You are concatenating strings to a string which in the end looks similar to this:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM game_table_entity_name WHERE column_name LIKE ExampleName;"
```

Where it actually should look like this:

```
String queryString = "SELECT * FROM game_table_entity_name WHERE column_name LIKE 'ExampleName';"
```

So do not forget to add the single quotation marks when you are concatenating strings with double quotation marks.
Everything that should be a string (in SQL syntax) needs to be wrapped into these "nested" quotation marks.

Anyways, using the [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room) Persistence Library is the recommended way to persist app data with an internal SQLite database.

Comment: Thank you, the single quote was it. I tried using regular quotes, but forgot it needs to be single quotes for it to work.